# Why doesn't my API request send on load of page cached by CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an Angular 7 app hosted on an S3 bucket that makes API requests to an Elastic Beanstalk backend. The S3 bucket is fronted by CloudFront, and I'm using Lambda to intercept requests for prerendering via Prerender.cloud. When I load my page (https://contrast.fm/calendar), the initial API request to load the page's data does not get sent.

This works perfectly fine in my local environment i.e. the initial request to my calendar endpoint gets sent. Also works fine when I load the site via the bucket URL. I've noticed that if I invalidate * in CloudFront, the request successfully sends on page load. But any subsequent refreshes of the page do not result in requests being sent.

Therefore, I believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how my site should be working with regard to CloudFront. Shouldn't HTTP requests made by the app on initialization be sent regardless of whether or not the page is cached?

Comment: Open your website in your browser. Press F12 to enable the debugger. Then repeat your steps. Are you seeing errors in the debugger?

Comment: @JohnHanley no I am not

Comment: For the case where the request is not sent on page load, what does the debugger show you?

Comment: Nothing -- there are no logs displayed

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your on page load. I am giving you tips, you have to then run with them.

Comment: Added a breakpoint to the beginning of my script -- still no logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this fixed! The problem was related to prerender.cloud. Prerender.cloud injects a monkey patch that caches AJAX requests.

[image: prerender monkey patch]

To resolve, you can put `prerendercloud.set('disableAjaxPreload', true)` in `handler.js` if you're using prerender.cloud's CloudFront + Lambda@Edge library. However, this isn't ideal because it will cause the screen to flicker, since stale cached data will disappear and new data from AJAX requests will replace it on load.

You can also set `window.__PRELOADED_STATE_PLAIN__`. This disables the monkey patch entirely and is well documented here: https://www.prerender.cloud/docs/server-client-transition/state